# Cómo funciona la sesión en PHP con procesos grandes?

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación que tiene un tiempo de sesión de 5 minutos antes de que está expire. Luego hago una petición para subir un archivo enorme el cual demora 10 minutos. Luego de estos 10 el servidor responde. Alguien me podría explicar que pasaria con la sesión? Esta expiraría a los 5 minutos? Si el archivo carga en 2 minutos pero el proceso de respuesta demora 10 minutos... Que sucedería?

Comment: ¿El tiempo de sesión está definido en la aplicación o en la configuración de PHP?

Comment: El tiempo de sesión lo determina en servidor ya sea por que lo hiciste en la configuración de PHP o en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: Pero lo controla con PHP.ini?

Comment: Actualmente en el .ini

Comment: ¿Y lo que quieres es extender la sesión sólo para la subida de ficheros o te vale para todo? Porque una solución rápida sería poner un número más grande en el php.ini o el .htaccess. Pero eso afectaría a todas las sesiones y no sólo a las que suben archivos

Comment: Realmente lo que necesito saber es si el cliente está subiendo un activo muy grande, cuenta como tiempo de inactividad... Quiero saber si cuando el servidor esta ocupado cuenta como tiempo de inactividad... Con respecto a que se toma el tiempo de inactividad antes de expirar una sesión? Sería en el momento en que el servidor responde una petición? en el momento en que el servidor recibe una petición? O ambos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, si el fichero es grande y se demora la subida, la sesión expiraría mientras se sube el fichero y la subida fallaría. Una opción que tienes es extender el tiempo de sesión en fichero .htaccess:

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 600
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 600
```

donde 600 es un valor númerico con los segundos que durará la sesión (p.e. 10 minutos: 60 x 10)

Comment: Eso quiere decir que la petición no se recibe hasta que el archivo es cargado? Ookkk.... En que momento el timmer de sesión se reinicia para evitar expire una sesión.... Sería final de la petición o al inicio?... En caso de que el archivo no importe pero el servidor hace un trabajo que dura bastante para dar una respuesta.. en el momento en que el servidor responde ya estaría vencida la sesión?